# Handle different time formats in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time

I am working on a dataframe with a column regrouping different time format like

```
    Time                ID    ...
0   1 hrs 1 min 1 sec   1     
1   1 min 1 sec         2
2   1 sec               1
```

I would like to calculate the mean of the time column grouped by ids. 
My problem is that the time format depends of the row.

I tried to use the `mean()` function on the Time column

```
df[["ID", "Time"]].groupby(["ID"]).agg(lambda x: x.mean())
```

but it does not work. 
I tried to format to date to then calculate the mean, but the 
`format="%H hrs %M min %S sec"` only apply to the first case and I get an Error:

> ValueError: time data '1 min 1 sec' does not match format '%H hrs %M min %S sec' (search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `Time` to `Timedelta` and convert to seconds and call `mean`. Before doing it, you need replace `hrs` to `hours`.

```
s = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time.replace('hrs', 'hours', regex=True)).dt.total_seconds()
s.groupby(df.ID).mean()

Out[110]:
ID
1    1831.0
2      61.0
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you ! I replaced "hrs" by "hours", converted to TimeDelta and could directly call mean() function !

Comment: you are welcome. There is nothing wrong with using `apply`. I changed from `apply` to use directly `pd.to_timedelta` to make it faster. Just let you know if you still want to use `apply`